# How to generate random numbers with normal distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I want to generate random number that follows a normal distribution and within some range say [3,17].
I tried `normrnd` but i can't specify the range for it.

Comment: "Normal distribution" and "within some range" are incompatible requirements. A normal random variable has an infinite range

Comment: 'Normal distribution' is centered at `0` (can be shifted by addition) and is defined with 'mu,sigma'. If you want a random distribution ranging from 3to17 (all values more or less equal distributed) try: `round(rand(1,1000)*14+3)` this results in integer values from 3 to 17(14+3). If you don't want just the integer values delete/modify the `round`-command

Comment: @TheMinion But `rand` generates numbers with uniform distribution not normal distribution.

Comment: Can i use `abs(randn(1)*14+3)` ?

Comment: @Misaki. Abs shouldn't have any effect since the absolut of a positive value is the value itself. And yes my code results in a uniform distribution. I don't really understand what your distribution should look like. As Luis Mendo wrote in his comment. There is no Normal distribution with certain range. Do you want a gaussian centered at 10 with a width of 7? could you draw/post a picture of the graph?

Comment: Wiki page for the [Normal (Gaussian) Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).  The discussion over the distribution's support implies a quick look at the distribution's mathematics would be insightful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stats toolbox allows creation of truncated distributions

### Warning: This is no longer a normal distribution

The data will no longer follow a normal distribution, assumptions will be invalidated, and is generally **not** a good idea...

With no mean or standard deviation given for the distribution the following values will be used:

```
mu = 10; %center of the range
sigma = 14/6; % range covers mu + or - 3*s.d.
```

The distribution can be made and truncated as follows

```
pd=makedist('normal','mu',mu,'sigma',sigma)
pd=truncate(pd,3,17);
```

A sample of given size can be generated from this distribution with `random`

```
nrows=10;
ncols=5;  
data=random(pd,ncols,nrows);
```

### Example

```
hist(random(pd,10e6,1),10000)
```

[image]

It can be seen the data fall between 3 and 17, and appears similar to a normal distribution within these bounds... but due to the truncation it is no longer normal